# Unity image.enabled=false does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried both setting enabled to true and SetActive(true) to diplay a Gameover Image. However, none of them works. I have a public Image gameOverImage declared and set the gameOverImage.enabled in the Start() to false.

[image]

```
private void Start()
{
     gameOverImage.enabled = false;
}
```

Then in one of my function, I put:

```
public void killAt(Vector2 loc)
{
    foreach (GameObject obj in setup.GetActive())
    {
        if (obj.GetComponent<PieceInfo>().GetLocation() == loc)
        {
            if (obj.GetComponent<PieceInfo>().GetPieceType() == 'G')
            {
                gameOver = true;
                gameOverImage.enabled = true;
                Debug.Log("?????");
            }
            setup.deactivate(obj);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The console does have ????? logged but no gameOverImage displayed in the game view. The game is over because I couldn't click my game any more. Any ideas? I also tried UI text. It doesn't work as well.

[image]

Comment: Are you expecting an image to just appear or do you have an actual UI Image in your scene for this image?

Comment: @Eddge Yeah I just want to have a gameover image to show up when the games end. I don't have the UI image in the scene. It's in my prefabs folder. And I have it attached to the script.

Comment: it won't work that way if the GameObject does not exist in the scene you cannot activate it.  So if you have a prefab, that has an image on it, you need to instantiate that object.

Comment: @Eddge But if I put it into the scene, it will block my game view. And unchecking the box right under the inspector can make it disappear but it doesn't show up when I use either enabled or setactive. How do I fix that?

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity in order to activate an object you need to have it in the scene.  If the GameObject does not exist in the scene, or in your case the UI Element that contains the Image, is not in your scene `SetActive(true) or Enabled = true` will not have any effect.  You will need to `instantiate` the object.  To make it exist in your world.

Prefabs, are useful to store a common configuration that can be used multiple times in your game but they do not exist in the scene, that is why you have to instantiate them.

For your GameOver Image you have a few options the simplest is this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class EnableUI : MonoBehaviour {
    public Image GameOverImage;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GameOverImage.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GameOverImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to instantiate it:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class EnableUI : MonoBehaviour {
    // This is a prefab that is canvas with your game over image nested as a child image UI under it
    public GameObject GameOverObject;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () { }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Instantiate(GameOverObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have dragged it to my scene. It still doesn't show up in either way that you provided.

Comment: @SeakyLone Did you update the reference on your script to be the one you dragged into the scene and not the one in the prefab folder?